# How do I sort a list based on three requirements?

Tags: list, sorting

I would like to have a list sorted based on three requirements. The list contains the object ROUTE of which the following three components will be used: profit, total distance, and an integer called apr.

I would like to add the objects in such a way that the list stays ordered from the beginning.

What  I came up with now is the following where I would like to add "ROUTE r" to the list

```
for (int j = 0; j < POOL.size()-1; j++)
    {
        if (apr(r) > apr(j))
        {
            // do nothing
        }
        else if (apr(r) < apr(j))
        {
            POOL.add(j,r)
        }
        else if (apr(r) == apr(j))
        {
            if (profit(r) > profit(j))
            {
                //  do nothing
            }
            else if (profit(r) < profit(j))
            {
                POOL.add(j, r)
            }
            else if (profit(r) == profit(j))
            {
                if (distance(r) > distance(j))
                {
                    // do nothing
                }
                else if (distance(r) < distance(j))
                {
                    POOL.add(j,r)
                }
                else if (distance(r) == distance(j))
                {
                    //add
                }
            }
        }
```

Could this work out well?

Comment: Have you tried anything in terms of code?

Comment: What  is the language you want to use ? (If any ?)

Comment: I have been thinking about code, but was not able to come up with anything yet. I'm coding in Eclipse (Java 1.8) @HopefulLlama

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorting in Java relies on two interfaces: Comparable and Comparator. Comparable creates a natural ordering of your elements, according to whichever criteria you want. Comparator can be used to have several orderings of your data.

When sorting a java collection through the method `sort` provided by a handful of Collections, you have the choice to use a specific Comparator. If you specify nothing, the collection is sorted according to the natural ordering of your objects (through Comparable).

Let's look at the implementation of those things now.

**Comparable version**

```
public class Route implements Comparable<Route> {
    private String apr;
    private int distance;
    private int profit;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Route other) {
        int aprCompare = apr.compareTo(other.apr);
        if (aprCompare != 0)                return aprCompare;
        else if (profit < other.profit)     return -1;
        else if (profit > other.profit)     return 1;
        else if (distance < other.distance) return -1;
        else if (distance > other.distance) return 1;
        else                                return 0;
    }
}
```

**Comparator version**

A Comparator is an object that does the ordering for your. By convention, a Comparator is different from the class it compares. So, let's write one:

```
public class RouteComparator implements Comparator<Route> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Route a, Route b) {
        int aprCompare = a.getApr().compareTo(b.getApr());
        if (aprCompare != 0)                        return aprCompare;
        else if (a.getProfit() < b.getProfit())     return -1;
        else if (a.getProfit() > b.getProfit())     return 1;
        else if (a.getDistance() < b.getDistance()) return -1;
        else if (a.getDistance() > b.getDistance()) return 1;
        else                                        return 0;
    }
}
```

**Sort a List**

Say you have a bunch of unsorted data in your list and you need to sort it before inserting new ones. To sort a `List<Rout> list` using the Comparable interface, just call `list.sort(null)`. If you want to use a Comparator, then call `list.sort(new RouteComparator())`. Easy, your list is sorted, efficiently.

**How to insert data while keeping the order**

This is a list, so the simplest way is to insert data while keeping it ordered is to traverse the list until you find a gap, and insert your new `Route` in that gap. If you are using an `ArrayList`, you can do it more efficiently by implementing a binary search to search for the gap.

However, if you are not bound to using a List, and your Routes are unique, then you can use a TreeSet, which is an ordered data structure. What's great is that it also uses Comparable/Comparator, you just have to specify it while creating it:

```
TreeSet<Route> t = new TreeSet<>();
// Creates a new TreeSet with the natural ordering of Route

TreeSet<Route> t = new TreeSet<>(new RouteComparator());
// Creates a new TreeSet using a Comparator
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you can apply a modified Bubble sort algorithm on your list. This is an example on Java (not tested), assuming an array of object with value,profit and distance properties as integers

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < array.length-1; j++) {

        if(array[j].value > array[j+1].value ||
          (array[j].value == array[j+1].value && array[j].profit > array[j+1].profit) ||
          (array[j].value == array[j+1].value && array[j].profit == array[j+1].profit && array[j].distance > array[j+1].distance) ) {
            int k = array[j];
            array[j] = array[j+1];
            array[j+1] = k;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If someone could say why it is wrong instead of downvote, it would be really appreciated

Comment: I am trying to understand your code at the moment. I want to insert one element, so I would say I only need one for loop?

Comment: This code takes a list of elements and sort them based on your criteria, this is an implementation of the well-known bubble sort alghoritm (you can google it). 

If then you want to add one value to the array and keep it correctly sorted, you can add the new element as the first of the array and then only use the internal for loop in my example

Comment: Thanks a lot. I do now know how to start, but I will be adding the elements one by one (was not really clear from how I phrased my question, I admit) so I have to come up with rules and decide on which position to add. In that way, the list will always be sorted and I just need to find the position to insert it?

Comment: This algorithm is a sorting algorithm. Insert your new entry wherever you like in the list, beginning, middle or end. Doesn't matter. When you want to sort the list, you pass the list into the algorithm and it will sort it.

Comment: - If i'm using integers there is no reason to use Comparator or Comparable
- If you consider his user case, where he will be insert one elements every time, Bubble sort is absolutely good and there is no improvements on using a merge sort

He was asking a basic question, so he is probably at his first coding experience and i wanted to keep things as simple as possible to give him a good starting point